# Allow cmd+` to toggle between most recent windows in TextMate

Tags: macos, mac, textmate

In OS X if you press CMD + TAB you switch to your most recent application. If you press it again you switch to the application you were just using (because it becomes the most-recent).

In Textmate, if you press `` CMD + ` ``, release, and then press it again it continues cycling through windows and does not go back to the most recently used window.

I understand that I can use `` CMD+SHIFT+` `` to achieve the desired affect, but it would be better if there was a setting to change the default behavior.

Comment: To clarify, this is the behavior in *all* applications; you just want to change it in TextMate though?

Comment: Interesting. I guess I never noticed this outside of TextMate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it works for all applications. But note that when you click inside the window, it switches directions. So as long as you click first, it will do what you want.

Comment: Very nice find!

Comment: Very cool. I'm primarily a keyboard user so this is a little odd, but I guess it would be fine. Any thoughts on changing how it works system wide? It's odd that the behavior differs between CMD+Tab and Cmd+`

Comment: Not that I know of (the only other thing I know is that control-F4 will cycle between *all* open windows in all applications). You should try looking around for some third-party software that might do this.